# JavaFx 2.0 + windows server 2008 R2 enterprise getting crash error?

Tags: windows-server-2008, javafx-2, java-7

I am trying to run executable jar developed with JavaFx 2.0 platform on windows server 2008. I installed java 7 on windows but I am getting the following error

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000070d921b6, pid=3340, tid=3468
#
# JRE version: 7.0_07-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.3-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [glass.dll+0x121b6]  Java_com_sun_glass_events_KeyEvent__1getKeyCodeForChar+0x11a6
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication1\hs_err_pid3340.mdmp
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication1\hs_err_pid3340.log
```

I try to setup develop environment on windows server 2008, but I am getting the same error. How to resolve this error ?

Kindly help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the simple solution for this problem. I have just upgraded my java version. Presently I am using http://jdk7.java.net/download.html **7u10** version for my application and it is working fine on windows server 2008 also. 
Although this release is not official release yet.. but I think I can leave with it.. until the official release of this version..

Enjoy.. cheers.

Comment: Hm I updated to 7u10 and it did give some progress. At first (7u9) the jar file just crashed. With 7u10 it starts, however as soon as you use the menu bar items the program seems to crash. Buttons and other stuff on the content pane seems to work ok, once these have been used, the menu bar seems to work as intended.

Comment: may be you could try 8 version now.. it is still in developers mode.. but has fixed most of the Javafx issues.. try that and let me know how it goes...

Comment: Still no succes it seems. Same behaviour as with 7u10 :( I also notice that the font on e.g. buttons is different than on my develop pc (without using custom fonts). Still error with the glass.dll: `# Problematic frame:
# C  [glass.dll+0x144e0]  Java_com_sun_glass_events_KeyEvent__1getKeyCodeForChar+0x17b0`

Comment: I haven't particularly tried your use case.. you should log this error in JavaFX JIRA http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa . Hopefully you will get the solution soon

Answer (score 3):

Had same access violation as stated above. What worked for me was to setup "Desktop Experience" under Server Manager in Windows 2008 R2. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

There is a JIRA issue that seems to match this problem - see http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23456

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).